# Impossible to use sum in a dataframe while similar code works

Tags: python, pandas, sum, dataframe

I am taking dataquest.io and I observed something strange (but could not get any answer back there). I am wondering why I can't use a code snippet that worked before in a situation that use the same kind/type of data, and should not cause an exception.

The lesson first teach to fit a regressor on a same training set and to predict on the same values, the calculating MSE.
Then it shows that it would overfit and propose a randomization process to avoid that. Problem being, apart from the random splitting, the dataframes generated are very similar, but if I try to calculate my MSE on the final results, it fails poorly, and I have to change the code for an alternative.

Here are both codes:

**First code**

```
# Import the linear regression class
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Initialize the linear regression class.
regressor = LinearRegression()

# We're using 'value' as a predictor, and making predictions for 'next_day'.
# The predictors need to be in a dataframe.
# We pass in a list when we select predictor columns from "sp500" to
# force pandas not to generate a series.
# (?) I could not figure out why it is not necessary for "to_predict"
predictors = sp500[["value"]]
to_predict = sp500["next_day"]

# Train the linear regression model on our dataset.
regressor.fit(predictors, to_predict)

# Generate a list of predictions with our trained linear regression model
next_day_predictions = regressor.predict(predictors)
print(next_day_predictions)
MSE_frame=(next_day_predictions-to_predict)**2
#(?) can math.pow(frame_difference, 2) be used on a dataframe?
mse=MSE_frame.sum()/len(MSE_frame.index)


______________________________________________________________________________
```

**Second code**

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Set a random seed to make the shuffle deterministic.
np.random.seed(1)
random.seed(1)
#(?) are there any difference between both of these statements? Are they 
# both necessary or just one out of two?

# Randomly shuffle the rows in our dataframe
sp500 = sp500.loc[np.random.permutation(sp500.index)]

# Select 70% of the dataset to be training data
highest_train_row = int(sp500.shape[0] * .7)
train = sp500.loc[:highest_train_row,:]

# Select 30% of the dataset to be test data.
test = sp500.loc[highest_train_row:,:]

regressor = LinearRegression()

regressor.fit(train[["value"]], train["next_day"])
predictions = regressor.predict(test[["value"]])
mse = sum((predictions - test["next_day"]) ** 2) / len(predictions)


regressor = LinearRegression()
predictors = train[["value"]]
to_predict = train["next_day"]

# Train the linear regression model on our dataset.
regressor.fit(predictors, to_predict)

# Generate a list of predictions with our trained linear regression model
next_day_predictions = regressor.predict(test[["value"]])
print(next_day_predictions)

sqr=(next_day_predictions-test["next_day"])**2
```

**Mistake was here, I was passing a with test[["next_day"]] while it was not done in the first code. Stupid me**

```
mse=sum(sqr)/len(sqr.index) 
#or
mse=sqr.sum()/len(sqr.index) 
# This is the line which failed while it was identical to what was      
#done before.
```

** it is worth noting both mse expressions don't yield the same results, They are identical for first ten decimals, but comparison with == doesn't give True.

Comment: What is the type of `next_day_predictions` obtained from `regressor.predict`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it is a class 'numpy.ndarray' of float64. Do you suggest I should type every outputs in these codes?

Comment: Just to clarify: How does the calculation fail? Do you get an error message or erroneous values?

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 324, placement implies 1

Comment: Can you please update your post with a full traceback?

Comment: Actually, I found my mistake and edited the code in consequence. Strangely, once edited, both sum uses worked, while with mistake in the code, I couldn't get either of these to work, so I could not reproduce exactly my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am not sure that I should not erase this question, now I see it is not really relevant?

Comment: You can answer your own question and explain the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was there:

sqr=(next_day_predictions-test["next_day"])**2

I originally wrote

sqr=(next_day_predictions-test[["next_day"]])**2

thus passing a list into calculation, which was not done in the first code.